# How to map an observable to another

Tags: angular, observable

I've looked at the RxJs docs and performed a search for this and cannot (surprisingly) find examples of what I'm trying to do.

Basically, I have two services.  One services consumes the other service and needs to map the response of the consuming service to another type.

Example code from an Angular app:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeesService {

  BASE_URL = 'http://foo.bar.com/api/getEmployees';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  get(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.BASE_URL);
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class MyEmployeeService {

  constructor(private svc: EmployeesService) {
  }

  get(): Observable<IMyEmployee[]> {
    return this.svc.get().map(
        (employees:IEmployee[]) => employees.forEach(employee => this.mapEmployeeToMyEmployee(employee))
    );
  }

  private mapEmployeeToMyEmployee(employee: IEmployee): IMyEmployee {
    return {
      ... simple property mapping to transform IEmployee to IMyEmployee
    };
  }
}
```

However, in "MyEmployeeService" the Typescript compiler is complaining "Returned expression type Observable(void) is not assignable to type Observable(IMyEmployee[]).

Even if I were to add return statements within the map operation I'm still getting the same complaints.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your single line lambda:

```
(employees:IEmployee[]) => employees.forEach(employee => this.mapEmployeeToMyEmployee(employee))
```

`employees.forEach(...)` returns `undefined`. Since your using the format `(...)=>...` instead of `(...)=>{...}` the lambda is returning the value of your single statement (`undefined`).

Change it to this:

```
(employees:IEmployee[]) => employees.map(employee => this.mapEmployeeToMyEmployee(employee))
```

`map` is like `forEach`, except for that it builds a new array from the returned value of `employee => this.mapEmployeeToMyEmployee(employee)`.